# MomentJS get the previous friday

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a user inputted date which I convert to a moment

```
var newDate = moment('01/02/2015');
```

What I need to do is get the previous friday relative to whatever date is passed in.  How can I accomplish this?

I thought about doing something like this:

```
moment('01/02/2015').add('-1', 'week').day(5);
```

but wonder how reliable it would be.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes I thought about doing something like this: moment('01/02/2015').add('-1', 'week').day(5); but wonder how reliable it would be.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
newDate.day(-2);
```

It's that easy. :)

`day()` sets the day of the week relative to the moment object it is working on.
`moment().day(0)` always goes back to the beginning of the week. `moment().day(-2)`goes back two days further than the beginning of the week, i.e., last Friday.

*Note*: this will return to the Friday of the *previous week* even if newDate is on Friday or Saturday. To avoid this behavior, use this:

```
newDate.day(newDate.day() >= 5 ? 5 :-2);
```